# PulseAudio: Redirect audio from null device to acual device

Tags: linux, audio, audio-recording, pulse-audio

I am trying to record my output audio at full volume, while also not blowing my ears off. Is there a way to redirect audio from a null device to my sound card so that I can record at 0dB, but listen at a much more sane level?

Comment: I'm not sure what this would achieve? A null device doesn't produce audio, so what would you be recording?

Comment: @grawity I would be sending all the audio to the null device, and redirecting that to the audio device, in the hopes that I could monitor the audio at full volume from the null device, but listen to it (while recording) at a lower volume. My understanding of PulseAudio is very limited though, so I could be completely wrong.

Comment: You can use `module-loopback`, as explained e.g. in [this answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/395417/193028). However, first I'd try to record from the associated `.monitor` source of your sound card sink - chances are that it'll give you samples at 0db, while the volume of the sink is implemented via the ALSA volume. In this case, you don't need an additional null sink. But I never verified this, and it may depend on details of the hardware.

Comment: @dirkt The loopback did the trick, thank you! I'll put this down as an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This has been solved (for me) by using `module-loopback` as pointed out by dirkt's comment.

To my default.pa, I have added:

```
load-module module-null-sink sink_name="dummy"
load-module module-loopback source="dummy.monitor" sink="[name of device]" latency_msec=5
```

This way, audio can be recorded from the null output at full volume, and my ears are intact.